# Can we treat a specific info as an error with Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I kwon I can use the `/wennnn` compiler option to treat the compiler warning that is specified by nnnn as an error.
But can I treat a specific info as an error ?

I want to treat the following info as an error, how can I do this ?

`info C5002: Omp simd loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'`

I tried `/we5002` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does `#pragma warning (error:5002)` work? (put it into an include file that's used everywhere)

Comment: It does not work and this is normal because it has the same effect as `/ we5002`.